# Docker secret mounts an empty string

Tags: docker, docker-compose, asp.net-core-3.1, docker-secrets

I have a docker service (inside a swarm) which uses two secrets as evironment variables (signing certificate and password for the certificate)

The secrets are created with this commands:

```
docker secret create signing-certificate signing-certificate.pfx

echo "mypassword" | docker secret create signing-certificate-password -
```

the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

secrets:
    signing-certificate:
        external: true
    signing-certificate-password:
        external: true

services:
  login:
    image: registry.mydomain.com/login:latest
    secrets:
      - signing-certificate
      - signing-certificate-password
    environment:
        - KeyFilePath=/run/secrets/signing-certificate
        - KeyFilePassword=/run/secrets/signing-certificate-password
```

Inside the (.netcore-) service I retrieve the variables with this code:

```
    var certPassword = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KeyFilePassword");
    var certPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KeyFilePath");
```

The certificate itself works perfectly fine and is present inside the service. The problem is the password: It is an empty string.

If I change the docker-compose to this it works fine:

```
environment:
    - KeyFilePath=/run/secrets/signing-certificate
    - KeyFilePassword=mypassword
```

So I suspect that something is odd with the mounting of a plane text secret.

I also tried these commands to create the secret:

```
echo mypassword | docker secret create signing-certificate-password -
echo 'mypassword | docker secret create signing-certificate-password -
printf mypassword | docker secret create signing-certificate-password -
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong? Or might it be a bug?

```
Docker-Version: 19.03.8 
Kernel Version: 4.15.0-96-generic Operating
System: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
```

Answer (score 0):

How does `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` handle newlines? Using `echo` will add a `\n` at the end of your secret, which will confuse some systems.

You can confirm this by running `cat /run/secrets/signing-certificate-password` and seeing if there's a newline between the output and your prompt.

If that's the issue, using `echo -n ..` should resolve it.